# Conditional probability with statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_1, X_2,..., X_{16}$ are observations with normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. We have two statistics:
$$ \overline{X}=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{i=1}^{16}X_i$$ $$ S^2=\frac{1}{15}\sum_{i=1}^{16}(X_i-\overline{X})^2$$
Find $P(\overline{X}>\mu|S^2>\sigma^2).$

The answer is 0.5, but I'm not sure how to bite it.

Answer (score 4):

For Gaussian variables, $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are independent. This should be a theorem (maybe an exercise) in a standard textbook like *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger.

Consequently, $P(\bar X > \mu\vert S^2 > \sigma^2)=P(\bar X > \mu)$. Because your $X_i$ are $iid$ Gaussian, conditioning on the sample variance does not change anything. That's what independence means.

Next, note that $\bar X\sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{16})$.

Since $\mu$ is also the median of a Gaussian variable like $\bar X$, the probability of being above $\mu$ is $0.5$.

Answer (score 2):

An intuitive solution is that, if $X_i$ are all iid as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\overline{X}\sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{16})$. The increasing or decreasing of the variance of a Gaussian random variable does not change the probability of sampling a value greater or smaller than its mean. In that sense, $(\overline{X}>\mu)\perp (S^{2}>\sigma^{2})$. Therefore, $P(\overline{X}>\mu|S^{2}>\sigma^{2})=P(\overline{X}>\mu)=0.5$.